# IPSec iptables rules for local service

Tags: iptables, ipsec, strongswan, rhel8

I have a StrongSwan IPSec remote access server running on RHEL and a client all on the same local network. I have a Samba server running on the same RHEL host that I want to be available through the VPN but not outside the tunnel. I can get the IPSec tunnel up successfully (had to make a MacOS profile with Apple Configurator2 enabling Perfect Forward Security in order to have a ciphersuite match) but I can't get traffic to route within the server properly. I did a packet capture and I could see the inbound ESP and decrypted ICMP packets from a ping from the client but the server couldn't reply back. I've spent several weekends trying to find out which iptables rules I need to get connectivity up but I think I'm missing some sort of understanding. I've been able to set up OpenVPN and WireGuard VPNs no problem with the tun interfaces but IPSec per my understanding is decrypted by policy in the kernel so I'm not familiar with how that would affect routing.

I've based my setup off the official StrongSwan example docs for [remote access](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/ip-pool/), used this [swanctl config doc](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Swanctlconf), read forum posts and translated the older format to the newer one with [this](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Fromipsecconf) - as well as read about [forwarding](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling) and [route-based VPNs](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/RouteBasedVPN#XFRM-Interfaces-on-Linux) - but I think I'm just missing the high-level understanding about how the traffic routes within the VPN server.

**Logical Network Diagram**

[Logical Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3833.png)

**swanctl.conf (with commented other things I've tried)**

```
connections {
        ikev2-vpn {
                fragmentation=yes
                rekey_time=0s
                #mobike = no
                version=2
                proposals=aes256gcm16-prfsha384-ecp384
                remote_addrs=%any
                local_addrs=192.168.1.15
                #vips=10.0.3.1
                #remote_addrs=192.168.1.23
                #pools=10.0.3.0/24
                #encap=yes
                #dpd_delay=300s
                pools=pool1,pool2
        #if_id_in=6
        #if_id_out=6
                children {
                        ikev2-vpn {
                                #start_action=none
                                esp_proposals=aes256gcm16-prfsha384-ecp384
                                #local_ts=10.0.3.1/32
                                local_ts=10.0.1.0/24
                                remote_ts=10.0.2.0/24
                                #remote_ts=10.0.3.10-10.0.3.200
                                #dpd_action=clear
                                updown=/usr/libexec/strongswan/_updown iptables
                        }

                }
                local {
                        auth=ecdsa-384-sha384
                        certs = /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/certs/server.crt
                        id = 192.168.1.15
                }
                remote {
                        auth=ecdsa-384-sha384
                        id = %any
                }
        }
}
pools {
        pool1 {
                #addrs=10.0.3.0/24
                addrs=10.0.1.0/24
        }
        pool2 {
                #addrs=10.0.3.10-10.0.3.200
                addrs=10.0.2.0/24
        }
}
secrets {
        ecdsa-server {
                file=/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/private/server.key
        }
        ecdsa-client {
                file=/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/private/client.key
        }
}
authorities {
        certauthority {
                cacert = /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/cacerts/ca.crt
        }
}
```

**swanctl --list-sas**

```
ikev2-vpn: #2, ESTABLISHED, IKEv2, c98d6dc49ca0acd4_i 85342c9a0809e294_r*
  local  '192.168.1.15' @ 192.168.1.15[4500]
  remote 'client2.vpn' @ 192.168.1.23[4500] [10.0.1.1]
  AES_GCM_16-256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_384/ECP_384
  established 53s ago
  ikev2-vpn: #4, reqid 1, INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP:AES_GCM_16-256
    installed 53s ago, rekeying in 3247s, expires in 3907s
    in  c334ea0b,      0 bytes,     0 packets
    out 021348d4,      0 bytes,     0 packets
    local  10.0.1.0/24
    remote 10.0.2.0/24
```

**swanctl --list-conns**

```
ikev2-vpn: IKEv2, no reauthentication, no rekeying
  local:  192.168.1.15
  remote: %any
  local public key authentication:
    id: 192.168.1.15
    certs: [CERT_DN]
  remote public key authentication:
    id: %any
  ikev2-vpn: TUNNEL, rekeying every 3600s
    local:  10.0.1.0/24
    remote: 10.0.2.0/24
```

**ip -s xfrm state**

```
src 192.168.1.15 dst 192.168.1.23
        proto esp spi 0x021348d4(34818260) reqid 1(0x00000001) mode tunnel
        replay-window 0 seq 0x00000000 flag af-unspec (0x00100000)
        aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) [KEY] (288 bits) 128
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
        lifetime config:
          limit: soft (INF)(bytes), hard (INF)(bytes)
          limit: soft (INF)(packets), hard (INF)(packets)
          expire add: soft 3418(sec), hard 3960(sec)
          expire use: soft 0(sec), hard 0(sec)
        lifetime current:
          0(bytes), 0(packets)
          add [TIME] use -
        stats:
          replay-window 0 replay 0 failed 0
src 192.168.1.23 dst 192.168.1.15
        proto esp spi 0xc334ea0b(3275024907) reqid 1(0x00000001) mode tunnel
        replay-window 32 seq 0x00000000 flag af-unspec (0x00100000)
        aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) [KEY] (288 bits) 128
        anti-replay context: seq 0xc, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000fff
        lifetime config:
          limit: soft (INF)(bytes), hard (INF)(bytes)
          limit: soft (INF)(packets), hard (INF)(packets)
          expire add: soft 3300(sec), hard 3960(sec)
          expire use: soft 0(sec), hard 0(sec)
        lifetime current:
          1008(bytes), 12(packets)
          add [TIME] use [TIME]
        stats:
          replay-window 0 replay 0 failed 0
```

**ip xfrm policy show**

```
src 10.0.1.0/24 dst 10.0.2.0/24 
        dir out priority 375423 ptype main 
        tmpl src 192.168.1.15 dst 192.168.1.23
                proto esp spi 0x021348d4 reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.0.2.0/24 dst 10.0.1.0/24 
        dir fwd priority 375423 ptype main 
        tmpl src 192.168.1.23 dst 192.168.1.15
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.0.2.0/24 dst 10.0.1.0/24 
        dir in priority 375423 ptype main 
        tmpl src 192.168.1.23 dst 192.168.1.15
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main
```

**iptables-save**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [22858074:106762962340]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [7:588]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13832427:3964756363]
COMMIT
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [22858911:106763119967]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13832428:3964756655]
COMMIT
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [22858911:106763119967]
:INPUT ACCEPT [22858308:106763007491]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [7:588]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13832428:3964756655]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [13833383:3964877586]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [186346:34394324]
:INPUT ACCEPT [185651:34259782]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [16086:1727773]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [16085:1727689]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/24 -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Generated by iptables-save
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [22831621:106727043679]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13832420:3964757167]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.2.0/24 -d 10.0.1.0/24 -i enp0s31f6 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.1.0/24 -d 10.0.2.0/24 -o enp0s31f6 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you add what IP you ping and what IP you're trying to reach Samba on?

Comment: Sure. Not sure if the network diagram shows it well or if I didn't explain it well but I'm pinging from the client at 10.0.2.1 to the StrongSwan/Samba server at 10.0.1.1. It reaches the server and is decrypted but doesn't route back to the client. And I would like the Samba server to be accessible from the same 10.0.1.1 as the StrongSwan server since it's the same physical machine in the same RHEL system.